# R xts object plot separate axis

Tags: r, plot, xts

Example:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
matrix_xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, dateFormat='Date')
matrix_xts[,1] = matrix_xts[,1] * 100
plot(matrix_xts)
```

If i plot this it will be hard to visualize the data. Is it possible somehow to have the first column be plotted on the secondary y -axis in xts.plot?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge this isn't supported with xts plotting. (Also some people do not favour plotting with 2 different axes on a single plot for a variety of reasons such as it could be seen as misleading.)

Here is one work around.  Plot the columns with different scales on different plots:

```
# Get latest version of xts for nice new plot tools (>= 0.10 not yet on CRAN)
library(devtools)
install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")
plot(matrix_xts[, 2:4])
lines(matrix_xts[,1], on = NA)
```

`?plot.xts` for xts version >=0.10 has some helpful examples for options related to the plot like colours, etc.

[image]